# Using NRF24L01 between 2 arduinos to send multiple sensor values

Tags: arduino

I have been looking everywhere for the answer to this but I am stumped. I have 2 arduinos which are communicating using NRF24L01 transceivers. I want to send 2 sensor values over, one is a float and one is an integer. I tried:

1) Sending them individually. The values seem to interfere when printing, creating an extra 0 and newline character at each loop.

2) Combining both values in a string. The string is unreadable at the other side.

I am trying to get the data in the following format:

sensor1Val, sensor2Val

Here is an example of my transmitter code:

```
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <printf.h>
#include <RF24.h>
#include <RF24_config.h>

RF24 Transmitter(9, 10);

const byte address[6] = {"00001"};

int sensorVal1 = 0;
float sensorVal2 = 2.5;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);

//TRANSMITTER STUFF//
Transmitter.begin(); 
Transmitter.openWritingPipe(address); 
Transmitter.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN); 
Transmitter.setChannel(87); 
Transmitter.setDataRate(RF24_250KBPS); 
Transmitter.stopListening(); 
}



void loop() 
{
Serial.print(sensorVal1);
Serial.print(", ");
Serial.println(sensorVal2);

Transmitter.write(&sensorVal1, sizeof(sensorVal1));
Transmitter.write(&sensorVal2, sizeof(sensorVal2));
delay(1000); //Wait 1s between measurements
sensorVal1++;
sensorVal2++;
}
```

Here is an example of my receiver code:

```
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <printf.h>
#include <RF24.h>
#include <RF24_config.h>

RF24 Receiver(9, 10); 


const byte address[6] = {"00001"}; 
at a certain address (integer, 6)

int receive1;
float receive2;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600); 
Receiver.begin(); 
Receiver.openReadingPipe(0, address); 
Receiver.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN); 
Receiver.setChannel(87);
Receiver.setDataRate(RF24_250KBPS); 
Receiver.startListening(); 

}

void loop() {


 if (Receiver.available()) { 

    Receiver.read(&receive1, sizeof(receive1)); 
    Receiver.read(&receive2, sizeof(receive2));

    Serial.print(receive1);
    Serial.print(", ");
    Serial.println(receive2);

    delay(100);

   }
 }
```

I am brand new to arduino's so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Send the data using structure.

```
struct MyStruct {

  int sensorVal1;
  float sensorVal2;

};
```

**Sender Code**

```
MyStruct myStruct;
// initialise the members of the structure with the values you want
Transmitter.write(&myStruct, sizeof(myStruct));
```

**Receiver Side**

```
MyStruct myStruct;
Receiver.read(&myStruct, sizeof(myStruct));
```